# Is there a way to have a "hover graph" instead of "hover text" when moving over points on an existing graph in Plotly Python?

Tags: python, hover, plotly, plotly-dash

Simple line graph in plotly but, when I hover over the points, each point brings up another static graph on the hover- for the example the graph on hover can by the below original line graph.

Simple Line Graph:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")

fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", color="country", title="layout.hovermode='closest' (the default)")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

fig.show()
```

Comment: That's true, but where is the problem? Do you want to delete the static graph?

Comment: Do you mean you want to utilize the points on the graph to do something on them ?